# Multiple & multi-step time series forecast training data with RNN

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks, forecasting, data-transformation

I have read a lot of discussion on how to do cross-validation on time series data (e.g. walk forward) but I failed to understand **how to properly prepare the training data** for multiple time series forecast, especially with deep learning models like RNN which require training with the whole dataset more than once (epochs >1).

Let's assume I have a dataset with 3-year sales data for different products. I am going to use an RNN (or LSTM/GRU) with encoder-decoder architecture to predict future 10 days sales.

*Data*

```
3 x 365 data point for each product (here assume we have only 3)

Product A: a1, a2, a3, ..., a1095
Product B: b1, b2, b3, ..., b1095
Product C: c1, c2, c3, ..., c1095
```

*Model*

Say I want to use a sliding window of 60 to predict the next 10 days sales. I could transform the data like these:

```
Input sales, Target

[a1, a2, ..., a60], [a61, a62, ..., a70]
[a2, a3, ..., a61], [a62, a63, ..., a71]
...
[b1, b2, ..., b60], [b61, b62, ..., b70]
...
[c1, c2, ..., c60], [c61, c62, ..., c70]
...
```

And my model will look like this:

[image]

with mini-batch >1 and epochs >1

**Questions**

I want to hold out 1 year of data for testing. so training data will include sales from 0 to 730.

1. Since each input of same product (e.g. [a1, a2, ..., a60] & [a2, a3, ..., a61]) are highly correlated, is it bad that I have [a1, a2, ..., a60] & [a2, a3, ..., a61] in same mini-batch?
2. Are sales sequence from different products independent? (so I could have [b1, b2, ..., b60] & [a1, a2, ..., a60] in same mini-batch.)
3. Most of the example I found use ARIMA model, which only fit the data once to train the model. Hence it makes sense to me to use validation techniques like Walk-forward. What about in RNN setting when I need to fit the same data multiple time to the model?
4. How should I properly validate the model with the 1-year hold out data? Should I use walk-forward validation?

TLDR: What should the training data look like when using RNN for multi-steps & multiple time series forecast?

Answer (score 0):

1. I guess you'll be using a stochastic gradient method, which is an unbiased estimator of the gradient. So shouldn't matter theoretically if you do enough iterations. A bigger batch size would help for sure. To be safe, randomize.
2. Also, shouldn't matter.